# SVM: Is it a problem if all the examples get categorised as Error support vectors, while training an online SVM?

Tags: svm

I am training an SVM online, however all the examples I feed it are getting categorised as Error Support Vectors. None of them is getting categorised as a margin support vector. Would this lead to a reduced classification accuracy? What should be done regarding this?